# 2D array passing

Tags: c, arrays, function

I am trying to pass a 2D array using (int **) to a function. However inside the function, I can only access first element of each row. how can I access the array like a regular 2-D array? or how can I access all of the elements from inside the function?

I am using the online compiler that is based on GCC V 7.1.1, and can be accessed via [https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_c_online.php]

```
#include <stdio.h>

void check(int s, int ** list)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; i < s*2; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ",list[i]);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int j;
    int x[3][2] = {{1,1},{3,4},{2,5}};

    check(3, (int **)x);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `void check(int s, int ** list)` --> `void check(int s, int (*list)[2])`

Comment: If you add a cast to get around a compiler error, you need to know what you are doing.

Comment: There's a vast difference between a 2D array and a pointer to pointer.  The storage that they describe is radically different too.  Your cast says "I know better than the compiler" — but the compiler knows better than you do and tried to help you by telling you that the pointer types in the call are incompatible with what the function expects.  But you decided you know better — not a good idea.

Comment: Additionally, in the function, you're printing pointer values with `%d`; that is non-portable at best; it won't work properly on a 64-bit Unix machine.  You'll need to remove the cast, change the type of the parameter in the function to `int (*list)[2]`, and arrange an extra subscript (e.g. `printf("%d ", list[i][0]);` or an extra loop to print the data — not forgetting to add a newline at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass an array to a function, the function receives a pointer to the array's first element.

But when you pass an array of arrays (also known as a "two dimensional" array) to a function, the function does *not* receive a pointer to a pointer.  The function receives a pointer to the (outer) array's first element -- which in this case is a pointer to one of the inner arrays.

That is, since you have the array

```
int x[3][2];
```

and you are calling

```
check(3, x);
```

the declaration of function `check()` must either be

```
void check(int s, int list[3][2])
```

or

```
void check(int s, int (*list)[2])
```

And then you need to decide how you actually want to access `list` inside the function, because `printf("%d ",list[i])` won't cut it under almost any declaration of `list`, neither the one you had or either of the two I've suggested.  (The `%d` suggests you're trying to print integers, but you need two subscripts to get from `list` to an `int` you can print.)

I rewrote function `check` as

```
void check(int s, int (*list)[2])
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; i < s; i++)
    {
        printf("%d %d\n",list[i][0], list[i][1]);
    }
}
```

and it worked as expected.

Alternatively, if you really want to iterate over the "flattened" array, you could write function `check` as

```
void check(int s, int *list)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; i < s*2; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", list[i]);
        if(i % 2 == 1) printf("\n");
    }
}
```

in which case you would call it like this:

```
check(3, &x[0][0]);
```

In this case function `check` is receiving a (single-level) pointer to `int`, not a pointer to a pointer.

Note that I haven't needed any explicit casts anywhere.  The cast you had in your original code, `(int **)x`, was a red flag, pretty much a guarantee that something was wrong.

See also the [C FAQ list](http://c-faq.com/), question [6.18](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/pass2dary.html).

Answer (score 1):

the passed parameter is NOT a pointer to pointer

the C compiler needs to have the size of the innermost index, so it can produce the desired code.

The following proposed code performs the desired functionality, compiles cleanly, etc.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define NUM_ROWS 3
#define NUM_COLS 2

void check( int list[][ NUM_COLS ]);

int main( void )
{
    int x[ NUM_ROWS ][ NUM_COLS ] = {{1,1},{3,4},{2,5}};

    check( x );

    return 0;
}


void check( int list[][ NUM_COLS ])
{
    for( int i=0; i < NUM_ROWS; i++)
    {
        for( int j=0; j< NUM_COLS; j++ )
        {
            printf( "%d ", list[i][j] );
        }
    }
}
```

this is the resulting output

```
1 1 3 4 2 5
```

to produce a pointer to pointer the code would need to be similar to:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NUM_ROWS 3
#define NUM_COLS 2

void check( int **list );

int main( void )
{
    int **x = malloc( sizeof(int*) * NUM_ROWS ); // be sure to add check for success

    for( int i = 0; i<NUM_ROWS; i++ )
    {
        x[i] = malloc( sizeof(int) * NUM_COLS ); // be sure to add check for success
    }

    (x[0])[0] = 1;
    (x[0])[1] = 1;
    (x[1])[0] = 3;
    (x[1])[1] = 4;
    (x[2])[0] = 2;
    (x[2])[1] = 5;

    check( x );

    for( int x=0; i< NUM_ROWS; i++ )
    {
        free( x[i] );
    }

    free( x );
    return 0;
}


void check( int **list)
{
    for( int i=0; i < NUM_ROWS; i++)
    {
        for( int j=0; j< NUM_COLS; j++ )
        {
            printf( "%d ", list[i][j] );
        }
    }
}
```